# Using VersionedTransaction in solana

Tags: transactions, versionedtransactions

How do i take advantage of versioned transactions for basic solana actions like making a token transfer… my goal is to make the transaction instructions significantly smaller so i can append other instructions…thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the docs on [versioned transactions](https://docs.solana.com/developing/versioned-transactions) and [address lookup tables](https://docs.solana.com/developing/lookup-tables).

Here is a [guide](https://www.soldev.app/course/versioned-transaction) on how to use address lookup tables and versioned transctions./

Comment: This was helpful… thanks a lot